# Censoring words in lua

Tags: string, lua, string-matching

Im currently making a discord censor bot for my friend, and I was wondering if any advanced scripters could help me, or if theres an easier way to complete my code.

```
local BadWords = {
    ['poop']=true,
}

client:on('messageCreate', function(msg)
    Msg = msg.content
    local msgs = string.split(Msg,' ')
    for i,v in pairs(msgs) do
        if BadWords[v:lower()] then
            msg:reply({
                embed = {
                    fields = {
                    {name = "Bad Word",value=v,inline = true},
                    },
                    color = discordia.Color.fromRGB(114, 137, 218).value,

                    --footer = os.time(),
                }
            })
            --msg:reply(('Blacklisted word: %s'):format(v))
        end
    end
    --[[table.foreach(msgs,function(i,v)
        if BadWords[i] or BadWords[v] then
            msg:reply(('Blacklisted word: %s'):format(v))
        end
    end)--]]
end)
client:run(Settings.Token)
```

Theres nothing wrong with it, nor is it complete but my idea was to split, or concatenate all the words they send respectively, mutate into all versions of the word (i.e. farm, f4rm, type shit) and then checking the BadWord list.

Mostly what I was wondering was if theres a more efficient way to do this, or if I j gotta do what I gotta do

Comment: *Theres nothing wrong with it* - then this should be on [codereview.se]. SO is meant specifically for problems you encounter and are able to precisely specify. If you have a solution that works, but are looking at ways to improve it, code review is the place where people can post different suggestions. Those can be largely opinionated, and that's why none could be considered a canonical answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, Should I re-post the thread, or is there an easier way of doing that aswell. This is basically my first post onto stack overflow

Comment: It would be best to delete this post and repost the question on Code Review